# How to give discrete input to a plant equation?

Tags: matlab, controls, transfer-function

I have a plant equation.Say,

```
Plant = tf([0 1] ,[1 1],'InputDelay',1);
t = 1:1:100;
```

Now I have a input value a= 0.0552 ,at the time instance t=1.I want to calculate output of the plant at t=1(which should be a numeric value as well!) How to do that!

If I give input a(1)=0.5552 at t=1 then y (output) is calculated based upon only a(1).

Similarly at t=2 my input is a(2)=0.4481(say)....

at t=3 ,a(3)=0.4100 ...So on.Then how would i be able to get the proper y(t1,a1),y(t2,a2)...values .

Comment: Use Simulink, it will take care of it for you

Comment: @percusse this can be done in MATLAB

Comment: Weird question: If your input starts at `t=1`, then the output at `t=1` is very easy to know, `0`. You did not give the system time to react. Why do you want to know the output at `t=1`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Yes but simulink is the reason not to do these by hand.

Comment: @percusse Look at my answer. It takes *more* effort to do this system in simulink than adding 3 lines of code to what he has. Doing things in MATLAB is **not** doing them by hand

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know how to use it pretty OK. I'm talking about people who are new to simulation should be better off using simulink instead of finding about StepOptions structs which are pretty new and not accessible to many people using university's/company's old matlab

Comment: @percusse I like Simulink. I still disagree. Also, `StepOptions` were introduced almost 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have a step input of value `0.0552`. You can easily use the function `step` for this as:

```
Plant = tf([0 1] ,[1 1],'InputDelay',1);
t = 1:1:100;
opt = stepDataOptions;
opt.StepAmplitude = 0.0552;  
step(Plant, t, opt);
```

That will create the following plot:

[image]

If you want not to plot, but to get the response, just catch step's output:

```
y=step(Plant, t, opt);
```

Comment: But ,what i actually need to do, is to get the instntaneous value out of this plant eqn. May be I was not clear (due to insufficient knwledge :P) Actually, I've designd a Fuzzy Cntroller(Manually without using toolbox) which gives output at each iteration until 'the plant' reaches some set-point value.I need to get the full respnse that is, Suppse,Iteration 1 > a=0.5558>then TF >O/P value(numeric not matrix) iteration 2 >a(calculated base upon 'O/P value')>TF>output value(numeric not matrix) ...store all O/P value genrated at each iteration.Then plot O/P vs time(or iteration)!

Comment: The instantaeous value at any `t0`, e.g. `t0=1` is `y(t0)`

Comment: yes that is it ... but if I give input a(1)=0.5558 at t=1 then y is calculated based upon only a(1).But,at t=2 my input is  a(2)=0.4481(say)....at t=3 ,a(3)=0.4100 ...So on.Then how would i be able to get the proper y(t1,a1),y(t2,a2)...values .Hope I am clear!  :'(

Comment: @SaritHati then the description of you problem is wrong. Please, try to add all the information in the question

Comment: I am Sorry @Ander !!

Answer (score 0):

I find this after long search..Instead of using the equation in laplace form.We have to use the differential form the with the help of runge -kutta method it can be solved.( that is to get the output in numeric approximated terms)